# ASP.Net MVC jQtouch iPhone device profile/authentication

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc, jqtouch

I'm building an asp.net web application for an iphone using jQtouch.  How can I read the device serial number from asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1):

In short, I don't think you can get the device ID through iPhone Safari.

iPhone Safari, like any other browsers, works in a black-box model and only let through a selective set of information about the system, such as geo-location and device orientation. The [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/Introduction/Introduction.html) by Apple documents several features specific to Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the API's like JQTouch are interacting more and more with the device itself with things like geo-location etc.  When I need to get more into the device and hardware I use tools like PhoneGap that allow you to work directly with the device like a native app (almost) still using javascript to do this.  PhoneGap opens up the device functions to embed in your web page to leverage in your application.  The catch is it is still a web site, but is now an application and must be added to the device through the likes of the app store or market etc.

You can read more at www.phonegap.com . I have had good luck with it so far combining JQTouch and PhoneGap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm using Visual studio 2010 for development.  Would I still be able to use phone gap on a windows platform?